# GlassFish 4.1 OutOfMemoryError during FilterChain execution

Tags: out-of-memory, glassfish-4

I am using a web application for websockets in GlassFish 4.1 for quite sometime and it has been running well until recently I came across this problem twice. It caused my application to crash as expected and I have not been able to pinpoint the exact reason. Here is the error trace I get:

```
GRIZZLY0013: Exception during FilterChain execution
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181)
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:261)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:235)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:227)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:458)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.addCompletionListener(FilterChainContext.java:930)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.IdleTimeoutFilter.queueAction(IdleTimeoutFilter.java:249)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.IdleTimeoutFilter.handleRead(IdleTimeoutFilter.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

From the trace it would seem that **FilterChainContext.addCompletionListener** is getting called too often causing the ArrayList to increase greatly in size - eating up memory. What could be causing the server to add this type of listener so many times? Is the server receiving too many requests? Is this a GlassFish bug or does this simply have to do with increasing heap size?

For the moment I have increased heap size denoted by the flag **-Xmx** from 512MB to 2GB. Also enforced parallel collector for GC **via -XX:+UseParallelGC**.

It would be great if you could provide further insight to help solve this problem.

Comment: You might want to give it a try in [gf 5](http://download.oracle.com/glassfish/5.0/nightly/index.html) or maybe in [gf 4.1.1](https://glassfish.java.net/download.html), should it be a fixed bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long time since I have fixed the issue, but I would like to share the change I had to make just in case it helps out people facing the same issue - who are making the same mistake like I did.

The problem was in my application. Deep down in my code the application created a new object for every new client request. Like so:

```
Worker workerObj = new Worker();
```

Initially, when it was deployed this did not cause any problems because the server load was far less but as clients rapidly increased the memory was consumed more and more and finally it caused the server to crash.

The solution was to make a single Worker object and re-use for all the requests in a thread-safe manner.